# Is kubernetes nginx-ingress controller supports proxy protocol with Azure load balancer?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, azure-load-balancer

I am trying to expose multiple port with using only one endpoint, however I couldn't achieve that with Azure infrastructure. I think this is caused due to there is no any proxy annotation in azure load balancer service yaml.

Basically I am trying to use my FQDN with below structure. Also, I have successfully performed that with AWS-ELB. Could you help me that how can I perform this operation?

- FQDN:443 -> it reaches the main web app -> **This one works.**
- FQDN:RandomPort -> it provides an access to inside tool from external applications
- FQDN:RandomPort -> it provides an access to inside tool from external
  applications

Azure Load Balancer Doc: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cloud-provider-azure/blob/master/docs/services/README.md

Thanks in advance.

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout: "6"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-10T08:34:55Z"
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.20.0
    component: controller
    heritage: Tiller
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
spec:
  clusterIP: 100.65.96.38
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: XXXXX
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    nodePort: XXXXX
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  - name: YYYYY-tcp
    nodePort: AAAAA
    port: YYYYY
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: YYYYY-tcp
  - name: ZZZZZ-tcp
    nodePort: AAAAA
    port: ZZZZZ
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: ZZZZZ-tcp
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
    component: controller
    release: nginx-ingress
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: "LoadBalancer Ip Address"`

Comment: This should be supported. What does your service spec look like? Please post it.

Comment: The service yaml seems like above and I am observing the problem only with the tcp connections. Also, I am exposing those tcp connections like below. 

`helm upgrade nginx-ingress ./charts/addons/nginx-ingress --install --debug \
    --namespace ${NAMESPACE} --wait ${NODE_POOL_SUPPORT} ${LB_CONFIG} ${PSP_CONFIG} \
    --set-string tcp.10004=${NAMESPACE}/${X_SERVICE}:${X_PORT} \
    --set-string tcp.30115=${NAMESPACE}/${Y_SERVICE}:${Y_PORT}`

Comment: What's the meaning of "FQDN:RandomPort"?

Comment: I mean "abc.com:30000". I am exposing 2 containers with their custom ports via TCP.